# How do you call a class method from an instance method without using the class name

Tags: objective-j

I have a base class that implements some class methods. It's using the class name to infer what resource it is and remotely fetch it.

```
@implementation BaseResource : CPObject

+ (id)find:(CPString)identifier
{
}
```

I'd like to be able to invoke the class methods from an instance method like

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(CPCoder)aCoder
{
    [self find:1]; // This does not work
    [BaseResource find:1];  // This works but will not resolve to the right resource name
}
```

I don't want to use the BaseResource class name because it needs to work for subclass with different names.

How do you invoke a class method from an instance method without explicitly using the class name?

Answer (score 2):

```
[self class]
```

will do the trick.

For instance

```
[[self class] find:1]
```